# Function number_to_words not working correct but everything else works

Tags: python

If I try to execute the script like this:

```
python3 xxx.py.old 1515566654474 "HI, 32231233212"
```

As a result, I get this,

```
HI, 3 223 123 32 12
```

but the function `number_to_words` does not work. Why?

```
   import sys
    import subprocess
    import re     
    
    def number_to_words(num):           
        ones = [zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']                       
        tens = ['','',''twenty','thirty','fourty','fifty','sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']
        hundreds = ['','one hundred','etc','','','','','','','']
    
        if num < 20:            
            return ones[num]
        if num < 100:
            return tens[num // 10] + ' ' + ones[num % 10]
        if num < 1000:
            return hundreds[num // 100] + ' ' + number_to_words(num % 100)
    
        return 'More than 1000'
    
    filename = sys.argv[1]              
    text = sys.argv[2]      
    
    def split_numbers(match):   
        number = match.group(0).replace(" ", "")
        if len(number) == 11:
            return f"{number[:1]} {number[1:4]} {number[4:7]} {number[7:9]} {number[9:]}"
        elif len(number) == 4:
            return f"{number[:2]} {number[2:]}"
        else:
            return number

replaced_text = re.sub(r"\d+", split_numbers, text)
```

---

Update 1. I rewrote the functions, but now I can't understand why the script duplicates some values after recognition.

```
.py.new 1515566654474 "hello, 12345678901"
Input Text: hello, 12345678901
Digits: 1 234 567 89 01
Converted: ['one']
Converted: ['two hundred', 'thirty', 'four', 'four']
Converted: ['five hundred', 'sixty', 'seven', 'seven']
Converted: ['eighty', 'nine', 'nine']
Converted: ['one', 'one']
Replacement: one two hundred thirty four four five hundred sixty seven seven eighty nine nine one one
Replaced Text: hello, one two hundred thirty four four five hundred sixty seven seven eighty nine nine one one
```

For example, why does he write four in twice, repeats sevens, nines, and so on

```
import sys
import re
import os

def convert_number_to_word(number):
    # Define the mapping of numbers to Russian words
    number_word_mapping = {
        '1': 'one',
        '2': 'two',
        '3': 'three',
        '4': 'four',
        '5': 'five',
        '6': 'six',
        '7': 'seven',
        '8': 'eight',
        '9': 'nine',
        '10': 'ten',
        '11': 'eleven',
        '12': 'twelve',
        '13': 'thirteen',
        '14': 'fourteen',
        '15': 'fifteen',
        '16': 'sixteen',
        '17': 'seventeen',
        '18': 'eighteen',
        '19': 'nineteen',
        '20': 'twenty',
        '30': 'thirty',
        '40': 'forty',
        '50': 'fifty',
        '60': 'sixty',
        '70': 'seventy',
        '80': 'eighty',
        '90': 'ninety',
        '100': 'one hundred',
        '200': 'two hundred',
        '300': 'three hundred',
        '400': 'four hundred',
        '500': 'five hundred',
        '600': 'six hundred',
        '700': 'seven hundred',
        '800': 'eight hundred',
        '900': 'nine hundred',
        '1000': 'one thousand',
        }
    
    # Split the number into individual digits
    digits = [int(d) for d in str(number)]
    
    # Convert the digits to words
    words = []
    if len(digits) == 3:
        words.append(number_word_mapping[str(digits[0] * 100)])
        digits.pop(0)
    if len(digits) >= 2:
        if digits[0] > 1:
            words.append(number_word_mapping[str(digits[0] * 10)])
            digits.pop(0)
            if digits[0] != 0:
                words.append(number_word_mapping[str(digits[0])])
        else:
            words.append(number_word_mapping[str(digits[0] * 10 + digits[1])])
            digits.pop(0)
            digits.pop(0)
    if len(digits) == 1:
        words.append(number_word_mapping[str(digits[0])])
        
    print("Converted:", words)
    
    return ' '.join(words)

def process_text(filename, text):
    print("Input Text:", text)
    
    # Check for sequence of 11 digits in a row
    matches = re.findall(r'\d{11}', text)
    if matches:
        for match in matches:
            digit1 = match[0]
            digit2 = match[1:4]
            digit3 = match[4:7]
            digit4 = match[7:9]
            digit5 = match[9:11]
            
            print("Digits:", digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5)
            
            replacement = f'{convert_number_to_word(digit1)} {convert_number_to_word(digit2)} {convert_number_to_word(digit3)} {convert_number_to_word(digit4)} {convert_number_to_word(digit5)}'
            print("Replacement:", replacement)
            
            text = text.replace(match, replacement)
    else:
        # Check for sequence of 4 digits in a row
        matches = re.findall(r'\d{4}', text)
        for match in matches:
            digit1 = match[0:2]
            digit2 = match[2:4]
            
            print("Digits:", digit1, digit2)
            
            replacement = f'{convert_number_to_word(digit1)} {convert_number_to_word(digit2)}'
            print("Replacement:", replacement)
            
            text = text.replace(match, replacement)
    
    print("Replaced Text:", text)
    
    return text
```

Comment: *but the function number_to_words does not work. Why?*: What doesn't work? how is the output different from what you expected?

Comment: `ones = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']                       `

Comment: @TheTridentGuysupportsUkraine, I want the result to be number names, not numbers. For example,three three hundred twenty-three etc

Comment: @sahasrara62 it's just a typo, the quotation mark is there in the original

Comment: Please edit the question to match the original. There's also an indentation problem, the first `import` has one less space than the rest of the script.

Comment: You never call `number_to_words()` anywhere. You only call `split_numbers()`.

Comment: The reason you're getting the duplicates is that in your if statement `if digits[0] != 0:` you don't end it with `digits.pop(0)`. So, the final `if len(digits) == 1:` statement will also get entered and append the final digit again.